# Use html code as column name with ui-grid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am trying to change column name using html tag.
I dont know if it's clean but i want to use a  
on my js code to rename my column using ui-grid. some thing like :

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            enableFiltering: true,
            enableColumnResizing : true,
            enableHorizontalScrollbar : true,
            columnDefs: [
                { field: 'type', name:'<bean:message key="data.type"/>' }
            ]
        };
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.overviewImport;
```

dont ask me why i'm using the tag

But without showing the html code on my page !

thx.

Comment: your question is not clear.Can you provide more info ? what is `data.type` ?

Comment: it's just a property on my ApplicationResources.properties :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `headerTemplate` and `grid.AppScope`.